# What would the rails helper tag equivalent be of this select?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have been struggling to convert this to some sort of rails helper select. Can anyone help with this?

```
<%= form_with(model: scheduleevent, class: "contents", data: { controller: 'nested-form', nested_form_wrapper_selector_value: '.nested-form-wrapper' }) do |form| %>

... schedtimerange_form start ...

<%= select_tag "days[]",options_for_select(Date::DAYNAMES.zip((1..7))), id:"days[]", multiple: true, class: 'multis' %> 

<% end %>
```

The select tag is within a nested attribute partial called schedtimerange_form that is called like this:

```
<template data-nested-form-target="template">
  <%= form.fields_for :schedtimeranges, Schedtimerange.new, child_index: 'NEW_RECORD' do |schedtimerange| %>
     <%= render "schedtimerange_form", form: schedtimerange %>
  <% end %>
</template>
<%= form.fields_for :schedtimeranges do |schedtimerange| %>
     <%= render "schedtimerange_form", form: schedtimerange %>
<% end %>
```

Schedtimerange_form:

```
<div data-new-record="<%= form.object.new_record? %>">
  <div class="w-full">
    <div data-controller="select">
     <%= select_tag "days[]",options_for_select(Date::DAYNAMES.zip((1..7))), id:"days[]", multiple: true, class: 'multis' %> </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="w-full mb-2">
      <label class="form_label"><%= t("scheduling_events_new_lbl_starttime") %> </label>
      <div class="pr-4"><%= form.text_field :start_time, data: { controller: "flatpickr", flatpickr_enable_time: true, flatpickr_no_calendar: true,
             flatpickr_date_format: "h:i K" }, class: 'form_control', placeholder: "#{t("scheduling_events_new_lbl_starttime")}" %> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="w-full mb-4">
      <label class="form_label"><%= t("scheduling_events_new_lbl_endtime") %> </label>
      <div class="pr-4"><%= form.text_field :end_time, data: { controller: "flatpickr", flatpickr_enable_time: true, flatpickr_no_calendar: true, flatpickr_date_format: "h:i K" }, class: 'form_control', placeholder: "#{t("scheduling_events_new_lbl_endtime")}" %> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="w-full">
      <button type="button" class="font-medium text-red-600 dark:text-red-500 hover:underline" data-action="nested-form#remove">Remove Times</button>
    </div>
  </div><%= form.hidden_field :_destroy %>
</div>
```

Comment: `class: 'multis'` is not valid HTML attribute

Comment: Fixed it. I was going back and forth between tag helpers and html.

Answer (score 0):

```rb
  <%= select_tag "days[]",options_for_select(Date::DAYNAMES.zip((1..7))), id:"days[]" %>
```

Comment: Thanks! This works, but days[] is going through to the controller with a nil value. Any idea why?   

    `<%= select_tag "days[]",options_for_select(Date::DAYNAMES.zip((1..7))), id:"days[]", multiple: true, class: 'multis' %>`

Comment: @spacerobot it works for me, please edit your question and show your form tag. Did you get properly-submitted `days[]` params with your original markup (as shown in your question)?

Comment: Yes I do see the param coming through the params like this: `["days", nil]]` I have updated my post with additional form details.

Comment: @spacerobot am I reading your markup correctly? You have the select_tag helper in both the partial and also in the form in which the partial is called. It's included twice? If that's true, then that's the cause of your problem. But maybe I'm misreading.

Comment: I am using stimulus nested form for creating dynamic sets of these fields. https://www.stimulus-components.com/docs/stimulus-rails-nested-form/

Comment: does the select tag appear twice on the page?

Comment: It could yes. Basically I click an add times button and it loads the partial with the select tag. If I wish to add another set of times, I could dlick the button again and it loads another set. Like loading dynamic form fields. Even with just one select though on the page the nil days[] array goes through.

Comment: Well I don't know why you get `[days, nil]` on your page. But please know that you can't expect it to work when you have multiple select tags with the name `days[]` and expect it to work. When I do it (just form and select tag) I get ` Parameters: {"days"=>["2", "3"]}' when two days are selected. You should strip everything away except for the form tag, select tag, and submit button, and then start adding markup back until it breaks.